# Selecting n-random points within polygon as single feature in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: point, google-earth-engine, select-by-location, random

**IMPORTS:**

```
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[73.85016678395664, 14.304113379426035],
      [73.85016583974448, 14.048667693939866],
      [74.0477686190103, 14.155139129529527]]]);
```

**CODE:**

```
var fg_points = ee.Feature(geometry);
```

I thought if the geometry is given as a feature it will select all points in that polygon but it isn't.

How to select some n number of Random Points within a polygon as a single feature in Google Earth Engine?

Comment: Please include the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually, I am struck at the origin itself. So, I thought not to include that trivial thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the answer. If anyone did try the question and didn't get it. Here's the solution.

```
var fg_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry,n, 0, 10);
```

**Arguments:
region (geometry):
The region to generate points for.
points (n, default: 1000):
The number of points to generate.
seed (Long, default: 0):
A seed for the random number generator.
max error (ErrorMargin, optional):
The maximum amount of error tolerated when performing any necessary reprojection.
Returns: FeatureCollection**